# share / forward JSQMedia Message

Tags: swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

how to share /forward JSQMedia Message?
Is library support this feature.??
i have test the Sample project and i have seen an 'accessry button' beside each media item but i do'nt know how to implement this? or for what reason that button appers??

A sample code:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, didTapCellAt indexPath: IndexPath, touchLocation: CGPoint) {

        view.resignFirstResponder()
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, didTapMessageBubbleAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        if let test = self.getImage(indexPath: indexPath)
        {
            selectedImage = test
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showMedia", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

Any guidance and help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like someone opened an issue for this feature yesterday: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/2157

Comment: @Alex7: the given reference is also generated (issued) by me.